# isomorphism definition seemingly inconsistent with isometry

Tags: isometry, vector-space-isomorphism

I have currently learnt about ismorphism. What dazzles me is that the definitions to not seem to match perfectly. The usual definition that I find is:

Let $\boldsymbol A = (A,(f_i))$ and $\boldsymbol B = (B,(g_i))$ be two algebraic structures of the same type $(m_i),$ such that $m_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$ for each $i$ names the arity of the fundamental operations $f_i$ and $g_i$. Each $m$-ary operation is a special $m+1$-ary homogeneous relation. A relation $\varphi\colon A \to B$ is an isomorphism of $\boldsymbol A$ in $\boldsymbol B,$ if it is bijective and for each $i$ and for each $a_1,\ldots,a_{m_i} \in A$ it holds that

$g_i(\varphi(a_1),\ldots,\varphi(a_{m_i})) = \varphi(f_i(a_1,\ldots,a_{m_i}))$

Clear, understood. Now, we could define some metric spaces (that are merely special cases of some algebraic structure [or maybe I am wrong here?]) $\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B}$ with metrics $f_i, g_i$, respectively. Again, lets have the same type $(m_i)$. Now, if I have translated the definition of isometry correctly to our setting, it says that a relation $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$ is an isometry if it holds that:

$g_i\left(\varphi(a_1),\varphi(a_2)\right)=f_i(a_1,a_2)$

It is just intuitive by looking at the results that there is no $\varphi$ on the right-hand side because we would like to have equal distances. However, it does not match the definition in the first formula for the isomorphism in general above. And sources seem to be consistent in that they say that an isometry is an isomorphism, also called isometric isomorphism oftentimes.

So, is the first definition (first formula in my post) just no general definition or did I miss anything here?

Comment: Isomorphism of what? And no, I don't see any obvious definition of $f_i$ and $g_i$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have edited the post, hopefully it is clear now

Comment: I am not that familiar with universal algebra, but how are metric spaces algebraic structures? The maps they have go to the reals, not to the space itself.

Comment: Hm, you are right in that. But why is an bijective "isometry" then called "isometric isomorphism" if an isomorphism is defined on an algebraic structure? Or is the statement "an isometric isomorphism is a special isomorphism" just not true and the name is misleading because it is based on "similarity" rather than true specialization?

Comment: The term "isomorphism" is not at all limited to algebraic structures. It can be defined in any category (as an invertible morphism).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, so my definition above is not a general one but one dedicated to algebraic structures. And the only possible definition that matches "all" kind of structures would be by invertible morphism? Consider creating an answer that I can mark as solution

Comment: Indeed, the most general version is just as an invertible morphism. Of course, this then becomes completely dependent on the category (and indeed, the "same" map between some types of structures can be invertible when the structures are considered in one category and not when they are considered in another).